# Функция и динамический массив

Tags: c++

Написать функцию для нахождения суммы чисел в каждой строке двумерного динамического массива.
Как я исполнил, и если не трудно покажите как должно быть,если есть ошибки.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sum(int v1, int v2, int iP[]);

void main()
{
    int v1, v2;
    int *iP;
    v1 = v2 = 0;
    cout << "Enter size";
    cin >> v1 >> v2;
    iP = new int[v1 * v2];
    for (int i = 0; i < v1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < v2; j++)
            cin >> *(iP + i * v2 + j);
    cout << sum(v1, v2, iP);
    delete[] iP;
    system("pause");
}

int sum(int v1, int v2, int *iP)
{
    int s;
    s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v1; i++)
        s = s + *(iP + i);
    cout << "Сумма чисел в каждой строке:" << endl;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: У Вас ошибка в функции суммирования. При подсчете суммы Вы используете только одну размерность. Таким образом, Вы подсчитываете всегда сумму первой строки.

Comment: И зачем в функции суммирования этот вывод строки, не несущей полезной информации?

Comment: нет у вас двумерного массива.

Answer (score 0):

> Как я исполнил, и если не трудно покажите как должно быть

Если вы уж используйте метку `c++`, старайтесь пользоваться средствами стандартной библиотеки. Не зря же ее так старательно создавали. Выбирайте правильно типы, выбирайте правильно механизмы обработки.

Вот пример подобной реализации. Прошу обратить внимание на то, что подготовительные операции (создание и заполнение двумерного массива) занимают большую часть решения. А само суммирование - просто до безобразия:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>

using MatrixType = std::vector<std::valarray<int>>;

int main() {
  size_t Row = 2;
  size_t Column = 5;
  // объявление матрицы
  MatrixType M;
  M.reserve(Row);
  // заполнение матрицы
  for (size_t i = 0; i < Row; i++) {
    std::valarray<int> Tmp(Column);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < Column; j++)
      Tmp[j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    M.push_back(Tmp);
  }
  // печать матрицы
  for (auto&& i : M) {
    for (auto&& j : i)
      std::cout << j << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "Суммы:" << std::endl;

  // собственно расчет суммы и печать - неправда ли прекрасно? :-)

  for (auto&& i : M)
    std::cout << i.sum() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Ссылка на онлайн исполнение](https://ideone.com/iIcq3u)

Comment: Нужен заголовочный файл и указание нэймспэйса для `std::size_t`

Comment: Цитата: "size_t — это базовый беззнаковый целочисленный memsize-тип, определённый в стандартной библиотеке языков C/C++. Данный тип описан в заголовочном файле stddef.h для языка C и в файле cstddef для языка C++. Типы, определяемые заголовочным файлом stddef.h, расположены в глобальном пространстве, cstddef размещает тип size_t в пространстве имён std..."

Comment: "...  В связи с тем, что стандартный заголовочный файл stddef.h языка C для обеспечения совместимости включается в С++ программы, в этих программах возможно обращение к типу как в глобальном пространстве имён (::size_t, size_t), так и в пространстве имён std (std::size_t)."

Comment: Первая часть цитаты говорит о том, что надо добавить заголовочный файл. С ней я согласен. Откуда взята вторая часть цитаты, а конкретно *"стандартный заголовочный файл stddef.h языка C для обеспечения совместимости включается в С++ программы"* ?  Мои источники: [1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#5), [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5079325/13970074), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13889467/13970074)

Comment: Не хочу сейчас докапываться до сути, ибо даже по второй ссылке видно - можно увидеть `/*implementation-defined*/`. И там-сям пишут, что `size_t`, как тип глобальной видимости - включается в "основные" заголовки. Доказательство тому - мой пример в онлайн-компиляторе, который собирается без ошибок.

Comment: Это показывает, что это какой-то алиас implementation-defined типа, а не то, что заголовочные файлы с ним автоматически обязаны включаться. Собственно, сделал форк вашего примера без заголовочных файлов https://ideone.com/fqMv8J и получаю ошибку с замечанием *"‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<cstddef>’; did you forget to ‘#include <cstddef>’?"*. На то, что конкретная реализация может включать определённый хедер через другой (в данном случае `<iostream>` https://ideone.com/C4zGbC), не надо полагаться, если это явно не оговорено в документации

Comment: Тут - полностью согласен. О чем и написал. Явно это определение типа висит в "общеупотребимых" заголовках как включение. Ладно, за сим откланиваюсь. Возможно и не следует полагаться на популярные реализации компиляторов.