# Преобразование конкретных символов строки в int

Tags: c++

Мне даны 4 строки времени (например 22:38 22:42 23:45 22:39) мне нужно записать значения часов и минут в переменные int hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4, min1, min2, min3, min4.
Пробовал stoi(), но оно преобразует все цифры до :, а мне нужно как до, так и после

Comment: и в чем проблема разобрать строку, разделив по `:`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: Используйте [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

Answer (score 0):

вы алгоритм неправильно составили

1. разделить строку на массив строк через разделитель " "
2. строки массива преобразовать уже в связку `int, int`

для первого этапа подойдет класс`istringstream` (https://qna.habr.com/q/586289)

для второго этапа подойдет функция `sscanf` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string& replace(std::string& s, const std::string& from, const std::string& to)
{
    if (!from.empty())
        for (size_t pos = 0; (pos = s.find(from, pos)) != std::string::npos; pos += to.size())
            s.replace(pos, from.size(), to);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "22:38 22:42 23:45 22:39";
    int hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4, min1, min2, min3, min4;
    std::stringstream ss(replace(test, ":", " "));
    ss >> hour1 >> min1 >> hour2 >> min2 >> hour3 >> min3 >> hour4 >> min4;
    std::cout<< "hour1="<< hour1 <<" "<< min1 << " hour2= "<<hour2 <<" "<< min2 << " hour3= "<<hour3 <<" "<< min3 << " hour4= "<<hour4 <<" "<< min4;
}
```

Comment: [про `size_t`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186673/Функция-и-динамический-массив/1186678?noredirect=1#comment2066947_1186678) + лучше с помощью https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline читать, чем преобразовывать исходную строку

Comment: Это просто пример. не претендующий на совершенство и законченность. getline вернет мне строку текста. куда ее потом присваивать если нет массива? будет много лишнего кода для примера не нужного.