# Найти кол-во слов. С++

Tags: c++, строки

Код проходит 16 из 22 тестов, никак не могу понять где ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста)

---

*Дана строка, возможно, содержащая пробелы. Определите количество слов в этой строке. Слово - это несколько (возможно, одна) подряд идущих букв латинского алфавита (как заглавных, так и строчных).*

*ВХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ*
Программа получает на вход строку, содержащую произвольные ASCII-символы.

*ВЫХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ*
Программа должна вывести одно число - количество слов.

ПРИМЕР

**ввод**

Yesterday, all my troubles seemed so far away

**вывод**

8

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int res = 0;
    string c;
    getline(cin, c);
    for (int i = 1; i < c.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        (c[i] == 32 && ((c[i + 1] > 64 && c[i + 1] < 91) || (c[i + 1] > 96 && c[i + 1] < 123))) {
            res += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << res + 1;

}
```

Comment: А кто сказал, что слова разделяются одним пробелом?

Comment: То есть лучше искать по подряд идущим буквам?

Comment: Изменил так что работает не только для одного пробела, но всё равно не проходит 6 тестов

Comment: Вообще-то да.Сколько,например, слов    в этом комментарии?

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтоб кто-то разбирался с вашим кодом - давайте хотя бы URL проверяющей системы...

Comment: https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=38334&chapterid=111313#1 - вот проверяющая система

Comment: @ИльяЧетвергов, в условии не сказано, что перед словом есть пробел, а ещё, что в строке есть хоть одно слово...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот вся ваша программа:

```
int CountWords(const char * s)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(const char * c = s; *c; ++c)
        if (isalpha(*c) && !isalpha(*(c+1))) ++count;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    cout << CountWords(s.c_str()) << endl;
}
```

Все тесты пройдены...

Кстати, вас там в задачке просят сделать отдельную функцию :) Не думаю, что проблема в этом, но если есть условие - его следует выполнять :)

Answer (score -1):

Для подобных задач стоит использовать регулярки - это прям то, для чего они были созданы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  std::string str;

  std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cin},
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}, std::back_inserter(str));

  std::regex regex{"[a-zA-Z]+"};
  std::sregex_token_iterator{str.begin(), str.end(), regex};

  size_t count =
      std::distance(std::sregex_token_iterator{str.begin(), str.end(), regex},
                    std::sregex_token_iterator{});

  std::cout << count << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: При попытке ввести строку из примера, программа продолжает выполнятся и не выдаёт ответ. Возможно я чего-то не понимаю так как только начал изучать плюсы и не понимаю ваш код

Comment: Не хватает `std::` для `std::size_t` и `#include <cstdlib>` для него и `EXIT_SUCCESS`

Comment: @dIm0n size_t работает и без std, ну а cstdlib - да, стоило бы добавить

Comment: @ИльяЧетвергов ctrl+d введите

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186673/Функция-и-динамический-массив/1186678?noredirect=1#comment2066947_1186678

Comment: Блин, может расскажете за что минус то?

Comment: Наверное, можно детей сразу учить ездить, но неплохо бы все же сначала учить их ходить :)

Comment: @Harry вам не кажется что ставить за такое минус - субъективно? Регулярки - это хороший способ решения этой задачи, в отличии от посимвольного обхода. Ответ верен, а все равно минус - это не здраво

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Собственно, все, что я могу ответить: https://ibb.co/h2wdBF9 Если непонятно, то намекаю: как видите, я минус вам не ставил.

Comment: @Harry я и не предъявлял вам претензии - в моем комментарии этого не было. Лишь согласно вашему комментарию задал вопрос касающийся правильности такого довода

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вы же написали "*вам не кажется что ставить за такое минус - субъективно?*" - т.е. речь шла о том, ставить или не ставить минус, а не  том, насколько хорош тот или иной подход...

Comment: @Harry ну да... Я видимо потерял нить разговора. Предлагаю на этом закончить - к вам никаких притензий не имею